# Implementation of a Least mean squares adaptive filter (LMS)

Tags: filtering, signal-processing, least-squares, spectrum, digital-filter

Designing an **adaptive filter** (example : LMS filter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter) is *highly technical* and would need high skills in signal processing in order to code such a filter.

Do you think there is somewhere a *ready-to-use* sourcecode implementation of such a filter?

Example : a simple notch (band reject) filter with a certain fixed frequency ?

I follow here the pilosophy mentionned here (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/14202) :

> An alternate way of doing this is to use an adaptive LMS approach. The
>   narrowest notch will be achieved by adding a sine wave of the same
>   amplitude and opposite phase (same frequency)
>   to the original waveform.

Comment: Maybe it's similar to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17779/c-c-code-to-generate-texture-coordinates-for-a-curved-surface?

Comment: @Phpdna : No, the method of "Least squares" is not at all the same thing as "Least Mean Squares" adaptive filtering in signal processing

Comment: [TAANSTAAFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TANSTAAFL) when it comes to many things, including DSP - trying to throw other people's code at a problem for which you don't understand the underlying theory is usually a recipe for disaster. Spend a little time reading up on the theory and at least get a grasp of the basics - otherwise even if you get something "sort of working" you won't know how to debug it, modify it or improve it.

Comment: SigPack is an opensource library that has support for adaptive filters, see http://sigpack.sourceforge.net/filter.html

Comment: were you able to find something related to this?